# emulator error:AdbHostServer.cpp:83: adb protocol fault (couldn't read status length) in android studio 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

gradle plugin version:4.0.1
gradle version:6.1.1

Tried with new device, but issue persists.

Also tried downgrading the version,  but it didn't help!

below are the errors i get when i load the emulator

12:59   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_0 check failed: vkCreateInstance not found

12:59   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_0 check failed: vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties not found

12:59   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_0 check failed: vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties not found

12:59   Emulator: createOrGetGlobalVkEmulation: Warning: Vulkan 1.0 APIs missing from instance

Please provide some solutions , if any!

Comment: below are the errors i get, when the load the emulator

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But could you please add an explanation to all of your answers even if it is only a brief one. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.